# ListView below scrollview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to put a `ListView` below a `ScrollView` in android. I tried putting them inside a `LineaLayout` like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ScrollView 
      android:id="@+id/marketDetailScrollView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   ...
  </ScrollView>
  <ListView  android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the `ListView` doesn't get shown. I also tried putting it inside a `RelaviteLayout` and still nothing. Can I somehow have a `ListView` under a `ScrollView`?

Just to add something. I don't want to split my screen so that I have a half with a `ScrollView` and another half with a `ListView`. I want the user to scroll down the `ScrollView` which apparently is bigger than the screen size and then the `ListView` should start

Comment: fix the height of scroll view.. like `android:layout_height="100dip"`

Comment: you can have listview add the views inside scrollview as a header or footer to listview (without scrollview) or specify a fixed height of scroll view and add listview below it

Comment: In your scrollview, `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` means that your scrollview will take all the space to the bottom, so there is no more space for your ListView.

Comment: You are using `LinearLayout`, and you place your `ListView` below  `ScrollView`, plus you set the `width` and `height` of the `ScrollView` are `fill_parent` so the `ScrollView` will override and gain the display of the `ListView`, if you want your `ListView` appears, set a specific size to your `ScrollView`, `200dp` for example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend you to put the ScrollView Content as HeaderView in the ListView or do you explicitly want to have two separated scrollable areas on screen?

**Example for putting the content of the scroll view in the list view as header (one single scrollable area):**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    setContentView(R.id.yourLayout);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Set the adapter before the header, because older 
    // Android version may have problems if not

    listView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter());

    // Add the header
    View header = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.you_layout_that_was_in_scrollview_before, null, false); 

    listView.addHeaderView(header);

}
```

The layout of the activity would look like that:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView  android:id="@+id/listView" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**If you want two scrollable areas, you should work with layout weight:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView 
  android:id="@+id/marketDetailScrollView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1" >
  <!-- ScrollViewContent -->
</ScrollView>
<ListView  android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No I don't. So by putting is as a headerview will just create a scrollable view?

Comment: Yes ... that would create one single scrollable area ... I will update my answer and add an example

Comment: I still have two scrollable areas

Comment: Setting adapter before header will make android crash. Except from that part, this is great.

Comment: It depends on Android API. It has changed with android 4.1 (i guess). I didnt remember what was the correct way, but if it crashs after setting the adaper, then set it before setting the adapter to the listview or vice versa. I guess setting the header before setting the adapter to the list view should work on all android platforms.

Answer (score 0):

`Fill parent` wont work for you,
 change it to wrap content,  and give layout_weight 1 to scroll view also, then it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is not good to put listview in scrollview. but if in case it is required, you need to set the height of listview. Follow the link below to calculate the height of listview for fitting in scrollview.

http://www.jiramot.info/android-listview-in-scrollview-problem

Using this way you can achieve what you want

Comment: its not in scroll view its under scrollview

Comment: Ohh okay. In that case just use weight property and set weight for scrollview and listview in your linearlayout. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the the height of the content of scrollview and its element to 'wrap content'. XML will be like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView 
  android:id="@+id/marketDetailScrollView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
...(height will be wrap_content for inner element as well)
</ScrollView>
<ListView  android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will might help you..

Comment: This is may be because of your inner content of ScrollView. Can you tell me what is your inner content of scrollView?

Comment: What has the inner content to do with that? The scrollview is bigger than the screen

Comment: Check that any of the content's height is fill_parent/match parent or not. My code is working fine. Just check that it is working or not.

Comment: OP will be notified when u have posted an answer... no need to post comment under question everytime u answers...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is near to what you are looking for. I give you this code code but i have to tell that putting a `ListView` in a `ScrollView` is a bad-practice and you should not use this solution. You should work on something more correct and with no scroll view within scroll view.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/marketDetailScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- the views contained in your ScrollView goes here -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```