# Android Listview below ScrollView not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I have a relative layout inside to that i have scrollview and listview after that scrollview. I am able to see a scrollview with content. But next to that i have a listview inside a relative layout. I can't able to see my listview there. I think its problem with XML layout. on the coding part its working.

Here is my XML Layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layerlist"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailedid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="0dip"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/detailedimages"
                        android:layout_width="40dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detailednicename"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingTop="0dip"
                            android:text="nicename"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detaileddaterecorded"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="bottom"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingTop="0dip"
                            android:text="2013-11-29 10:35:00"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#999999"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                        android:layout_width="40dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailedcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:paddingRight="15dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dip"
                        android:text="Transmitting data from a monitor to a distant monitoring station is known as telemetry or biotelemetry."
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                        android:layout_width="40dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/resourceContainer1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/resourceContainer2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/resourceContainer3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/resourceContainer4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                        android:layout_width="40dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailedlike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:paddingRight="15dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dip"
                        android:text="1 Like"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/deliberateactions"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layerlist" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dactions"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dip" >

                        <TableRow>

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dlike"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/like_grey"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dunlike"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/like_blue"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dcomments"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/commentblue"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dfavourite"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/favourite_grey"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dremfavourite"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/favourite_blue"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ddelete"
                                android:layout_width="40dip"
                                android:layout_height="40dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                                android:src="@drawable/deleteblue"
                                android:visibility="visible" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layerlist"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/commentslist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comments"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1d66b2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entercomment"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layerlist"
            android:hint="Enter your comments here."
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#999999" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/writenew"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331849/listview-below-scrollview-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693628/1835764

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool i tried those links and still its not displaying.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17449582/1835764

Comment: @Nirmal i tried still no hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it now try it'll work..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EEEEEE"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layerlist"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailedid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/detailedimages"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailednicename"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:paddingTop="0dip"
                        android:text="nicename"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detaileddaterecorded"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:paddingTop="0dip"
                        android:text="2013-11-29 10:35:00"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailedcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:paddingTop="2dip"
                    android:text="Transmitting data from a monitor to a distant monitoring station is known as telemetry or biotelemetry."
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/resourceContainer1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/resourceContainer2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/resourceContainer3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/resourceContainer4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailedlike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:paddingTop="2dip"
                    android:text="1 Like"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/deliberateactions"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layerlist" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_images"
                    android:layout_width="20dip"
                    android:layout_height="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dactions"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dip" >

                    <TableRow>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dlike"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/like_grey"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dunlike"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/like_blue"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dcomments"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/commentblue"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dfavourite"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/favourite_grey"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dremfavourite"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/favourite_blue"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ddelete"
                            android:layout_width="40dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:src="@drawable/deleteblue"
                            android:visibility="visible" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commentslist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#1d66b2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entercomment"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/layerlist"
        android:hint="Enter your comments here."
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#999999" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comment_post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/writenew"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its not working. I have tried that too. Still not showing. And inside Scrollview content is dynamic. So i don't want to fix the height of the Scrollview.

Comment: Its working. Nice job. But one doubt. Why my scrollview and listview in equallly splitted section.

Comment: I have given equal layout weight for both scroll and linear layout.. So, both occupies equal height in screen.