# Scrolling entire layout with a ListView and another View

Tags: android, listview

I know that is not a good practice put a ListView inside a ScrollView, that's why I want to figure out what kind of solution can handle this.

Look at the image below:

[image]

There's a block with some stuff on the top and there's a ListView below, and all of this scrolls with the entire layout. So, the question is:

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have just a ListView and set a headerView to this ListView to achieve what you want.

Comment: God, so simple!! Thank you very much!! If anyone wants the code, here it is: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838921/android-listview-addheaderview-nullpointerexception-for-predefined-views/7839013#7839013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838921/android-listview-addheaderview-nullpointerexception-for-predefined-views/7839013#7839013)

Answer (score 1):

Use header View:
[ListView below scrollview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331849/listview-below-scrollview-in-android/18332355#18332355)

or Sticky List Headers if you want to make them stick on top of the listview:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

or use different ViewTypes with your own Adapter implementation:
[Listview: Only one list item with multiple textviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596140/listview-only-one-list-item-with-multiple-textviews/20596615#20596615)

Comment: Yeah, that's it!! The first link. I've already tried Aurélien's answer and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume the reviews shown there are in a ListView? To me they just look like a handful of custom Views stacked on top of each other, not an actual ListView.

Comment: Because seems to be logical. And I want to do that.